# Installed AirFLow 2.2.3 but getting error AttributeError: task decorator 'docker' not found

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Just trying to run the example in:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/example_dags/tutorial_etl_dag.py

But basically getting this (removed the try/except at the and and some comments, so line numbers might not match).

Is there something special I need to install?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/d/dags/tc70_test_script.py", line 27, in <module>
    tc70_test_script = tc70_test_script()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 2984, in factory
    f(**f_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/d/dags/tc70_test_script.py", line 9, in tc70_test_script
    @task.docker()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/decorators/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(f"task decorator {name!r} not found")
AttributeError: task decorator 'docker' not found
```

Comment: Please share the code of `tc70_test_script.py`

Answer (score 1):

You asked about [`tutorial_etl_dag.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/example_dags/tutorial_etl_dag.py) but your traceback shows `tc70_test_script.py` which you didn't share the code of that script. The tutorial DAG you shared doesn't use docker.

Docker decorator is part of the docker provider and works only for `Airflow >= 2.2.0` & docker provider >=2.2.0 (It's just a coincidence that both has the same version)
If you don't have the provider installed you can get it with:

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-docker>=2.2.0
```

Then you can use `@task.docker` as shown in [this](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e052fb52b62df4a1abbb9578a605c77045d0e4cd/airflow/providers/docker/example_dags/tutorial_taskflow_api_etl_docker_virtualenv.py#L65) example dag.

Comment: I copied the script to a different file so I could remove things trying to see if I could narrow it down more.  I got the same error on the full script, just posted the traceback from the reduced script.  Guess I need to update my 
  pip install apache-airflow-providers-docker>=2.2.0
thanks, will try it